# Silly c# array question

Tags: c#

Element 0 value:

```
TimeEntries[0] = "False,S,16:00,21:00";
```

Element 0 is assigned to:

```
timeLine = USER.TimeEntries[i];
```

I want to perform a .Split() on timeLine but it must be a string. What's the easiest way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like timeLine is a String, so it's not clear what you mean.  It should help if you post more code, and say how you want to split it.

Comment: You're right, thanks Matthew. ChaosPandion made some assumptions as to what I was trying to do. Being succinctly clear is not always a virtue of mine ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `TimeEntries` is an object array you can do this:

```
var pieces = ((string)TimeEntries[0]).Split(',');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Would never have thought I could type like that in c#- cool. I was trying .ToString.

Comment: @XO - No Problem, C# is full of surprises. I learn new techniques every day.